# Add a Git repo to a subfolder of another Git repo

Tags: git

Okay so I have a project that I am working on that I want to merge with a remote repo ("milk") so I can get updates on. I tried doing this myself a few different ways but had the issue of the files getting added in the wrong location. Here is a example.

Here's how the path looks for a example:

```
examplebase/nextfolder/folder2/folder3
```

When I merge the repos the files from the "milk" repo get added to the `examplebase` folder. Whereas I want the milk repo files to get added to the `folder2` folder. I tried `cd folder2` so I was in that location and then trying to get the files but I had the same issue of them being added to the `examplebase` folder. How would I go about adding them to a different location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make sure the path to folder2 is the same in both repo.

That would involve a [`git mv`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) of `folder2` in one of the repos in order to make its path identical to the one found in the other repo.

Then you can merge.